# Can distcc use ccache on the compile servers?

Tags: gentoo, raspberry-pi

I know that `ccache` can use `distcc` as a compiler wrapper, but can the opposite also be done?

I have a bunch of **raspberry pi** machines which use distcc to cross-compile their arm binaries on a x64 machine with a faster CPU and faster I/O.

Since I very often compile the same software on all the raspberries, I think it would be nice if the compile server could cache and reuse some already compiled objects with `ccache` to save some time.

Or is the main build time spent on the raspberries themselves anyway?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? I'm interested in doing something similar for a team of developers.

Comment: No, at least not yet. All the documentation I've read about it so far only talks about doing the caching locally. I'm not actively researching this, but I should of course ask in the gentoo forum as well some day. The question is still open for anyone to answer (or upvote) at any time, better late than never.

Comment: This is rather a workaround than a direct solution, but I read about mounting the same ccache directory on a shared (e.g. NFS) volume for all machines. But I haven’t checked how/if ccache uses locking. (I hope it does.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you mean if rapsberry pi A builds with distcc, you want the distcc to cache this on your server so raspberry pi B does not recompile this?

This can be done now that ccache has memcached support, so you add can memcached to cache the results (checkout the `dev/memcached` branch of ccache). You also don't need to store this on the same server as distcc. You could store it on AWS, and your raspberry pi's will only send to distcc any cache misses, which is effectivly what you want

Install memcache:

`sudo apt-get install memcached`

`export MEMCACHED_SERVERS=localhost`

`sudo service memcached restart`

And for ccache (After update to the branch I linked)

`sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev`

`./configure --enable-memcached`

`make -j4 && sudo make install`

You can then tell ccache the location of your server via:

`export CCACHE_MEMCACHED_CONF="--SERVER=localhost"`

See for more info:
https://gist.github.com/itensionanders/2bd0056027f8308d4cd8